# How to pass a parameter from useEffect to child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

My useEffect method is:

```
useEffect(() => {
async function getRoomDetails(){
  const db = getFirestore();
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "rooms"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
    console.log('Document');
    console.log(doc.id);
    console.log(doc.data().name);
    var channelNameData = doc.data().name;
  })
}
async function getRoomMessages() {
  const db = getFirestore();

  const roomMessages =
    roomId &&
    query(
      collection(db, "rooms", roomId, "messages"),
      orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
    );
  const querySnapShot = await getDocs(roomMessages);
  querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
  });
    }
     getRoomDetails();
     getRoomMessages();
   }, []);
```

and I want to pass `channelNameData` to ChatInput, as

```
 <ChatInput
     channelName={channelNameData}
    channelId={roomId}
  />
```

How do I do this? I also want to avoid  Assignments to the 'channelNameData' variable from inside
React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a state variable with `useState`.

Modify that variable inside your `useEffect` hook.

The variable will then be in scope for the rest of your component and you can pass it as a prop.

---

Make sure you handle the default state from before the effect hook has run (e.g. with a sane default value or a value that indicates a `<Loading />` component should be rendered instead of `<ChatInput />`)

Comment: Thank you for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the useState hook to create a variable for storing channelNameData.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [channelNameDataState, setChannelNameDataState] = useState(null)
```

Inside your useEffect, you can have a line that sets channelNameDataState.

```
setChannelNameDataState(channelNameData)
```

Then you would pass in this state to the child component

```
<ChatInput
  channelName={channelNameDataState}
  channelId={roomId}
/>
```

As for preventing assignments to the channelNameData variable getting lost, you should be able to combine the useState hook with localState to make sure you can persist state.

Answer (score 1):

Create state variable and assign value inside the effect,

```
const [channelNameData, setChannelNameData] = useState([]);   

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getRoomDetails(){
      const db = getFirestore();
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "rooms"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
        console.log('Document');
        console.log(doc.id);
        console.log(doc.data().name);
        //var channelNameData = doc.data().name;
        setChannelNameData(doc.data().name)
      })
    }
    async function getRoomMessages() {
      const db = getFirestore();
    
      const roomMessages =
        roomId &&
        query(
          collection(db, "rooms", roomId, "messages"),
          orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
        );
      const querySnapShot = await getDocs(roomMessages);
      querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
      });
    }
    
    getRoomDetails();
    getRoomMessages();
    }, []);
```

in jsx,

```
<ChatInput
  channelName={channelNameDataState}
  channelId={roomId}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah but modify the ChatInput to pass in 'channelNameData' and not 'channelNameDataState'